# API access to PDF documents comprising approval pages

Tags: api, pdf, scraping

I am looking to programmatically find, enumerate, and download the PDF files associated with a drug approval package.  For example, the drug HADLIMA has several files in its approval package, which are presented in a list named "FDA Application Review Files" in its [approval package page](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000TOC.cfm).  I'd like to be able to find the URL's to these documents via an API.  In HADLIMA's case, these would be:

- https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000ChemR.pdf
- https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000ChemR.pdf
- https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000MultidisciplineR.pdf
- https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000NameR.pdf
- https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2019/761059Orig1s000OEList.pdf

I want to avoid "scraping" and get to this list via an API -- is this possible?